# Outline view with autocompletion in Vim

Tags: vim, ide, vim-plugin

Eclipse has a feature (under Ctrl+O) that lets you choose a method or a variable, with autocompletion.

I am aware of the tagbar plugin for Vim but I'm looking for something that would show a pop-up (similar to what Eclipse does) and be able to get me to certain method after I choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin which has the functionalities I was looking for is [ctrlp-funky](https://github.com/tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky).

It works only with functions and methods but its enough for my needs and works with every language without having to configure anything (like ctags/cscope).

Answer (score 0):

No need for plugins, that is built into vim.

You could do , that's CTRL+X followed by

: File completion
: Line completion
: Omni completion
: Dictionary completion

You could customise the pop-up window the way you like.

> The 'complete' option controls where the keywords are searched
>   (include files, tag files, buffers, and more).
>
> The 'completeopt' option controls how the completion occurs (for
>   example, whether a menu is shown).

See for details: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'completeopt'

Comment: The OP is looking for a convenient way to navigate his project, not to complete words.

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual workflow:

1. Index your project with ctags, cscope or some compatible program. Using ctags as an example:

   ```
   $ ctags -R .
   ```
2. Query that index from Vim:

   ```
   :tselect /expan
   ```
3. Choose from the list:

   [image]

Note that Vim also comes with a more lightweight solution:

```
:dlist /foo
```

that will search through the current buffer and included files for `foo`.